# Resource not available error using Eclipse Kepler with Struts 2 + Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration, struts2

This is my first app written in Java and my first time using Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7, and Struts2, so I'm surprised that I even got this far since all I know is JS and Rails. Anyway, this basic web app literally is just supposed to output the string `"Success Page!"` when you enter that URL in the IDE while running Tomcat 7.

I viewed the Tomcat success page so I know the runtime server is working. Also, I am getting no red x marks in my IDE. The tutorial told me to add to the URL `getTutorial.action` of my completed web app in order to render the `success.jsp` view.

However, I get this error at the URL `localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action`:

```
message /Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action

description The requested resource is not available.
```

The error log tells me this :

```
    SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
    Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:76

SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:76
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: Action class [org.koushik.javabrains.TutorialAction] not found - action - file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:76
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more

SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

**My web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**My struts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

**My TutorialAction.java:**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.action;

public class TutorialAction {

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("Hello from execute");
        return"success";
    }
}
```

**My success.jsp view:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Success Page!
</body>
</html>
```

I am struggling to troubleshoot this. In Rails I'd throw in a `binding.pry` but here I am not the slightest clue how to troubleshoot. Best I can tell, perhaps the routing got messed up somewhere.

Comment: Are you aware about the concept of package?? What the error message tells is the action class TutorialAction is not found. I can see that there is some package statement. A java class should be inside the following directory structure. org/koushik/javabrains/actions/TutorialAction.java

Comment: This fails your FilterDispatcher initialization.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do not know what a package is. I was just following along with the tutorial but from best I can guess, is a package analagous to a Ruby Gem?

Comment: Here is one of the package tutorials for java. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm  And this is the official oracle documentation for java about What is a package?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html and how to create and use one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When struts2 app bootstraps it load the configuration from `struts.xml`. It parses that document and create config related objects and put them into the internal container. Then used this config objects to instantiate real objects like actions, results, interceptors, etc. It's important to specify classes in the configuration that exist in the application. Eclipse can only compile a Java files and even validate DTD of `struts.xml` but it will not resolve configuration errors. Struts2 is doing it on bootstrap. As a result you got the error that action class is not resolvable. To fix the error you should provide the class reference that exist on the classpath.

```
<action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">
    <result>/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Note, the result name `"success"` is the default name of the result and could be omitted.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. It was tough for me to contextualize these elements through the tutorial. There were a few things he glossed over and did not elaborate on. Oh, and like Aayush mentioned, can you explain what a package is? Is it analogous to a Ruby Gem?Thanks again!

Comment: In the `TutorialAction` you have written `package org.koushik.javabrains.action;`. I thought he mentioned this. It's a Java package, I don't know Ruby but it's analogous to namespace in C#.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman C Figured out the problem - for people for whom the program doesn't run even after appending the file in correct action file.

The thing is as struts2 releases its new version it's loosing support for some of the jars.

Adding the jar file (commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar) solves the problem and gets the application running.